# Eclipse; Escape Sequences don't work?

Tags: c, eclipse, escaping

I am doing a basic C tutorial. In an example this code was given to introduce escape sequences:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("This is a \"sample text\"\n");
    printf("\tMore text\n");
    printf("This is getting overwritten\r");
    printf("By this, another sample text\n");
    printf("The spa \bce is removed.\n");
    return 0;
}
```

The console output is expected to look like this:

```
This is a "sample text"
    More text
By this, another sample text
The space is removed.
```

Instead, I get this:

```
This is a "sample text"
    More text
This is getting overwritten
By this, another sample text
The spa ce is removed.
```

I am using Eclipse Cpp Oxygen on Windows and the Cygwin toolchain to compile und run the code. I don't know what I'm doing wrong and I thought I'd ask here for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The console built in to Eclipse does not support the `\r`, `\b` (and `\f`) characters.

There is a long standing bug [76936](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=76936) for this which has been open for 14 years. But doesn't look like being fixed.

Answer (score -1):

In linux you example works exactly as you expect. Probably in windows the \r is considered like \n.
Instead on linux terminal the \r put (correctly) the cursor on the first char of the row.

Comment: No need to speculate.  Windows handles `\r` fine, in general. Evidently it's an Eclipse thing, not a Windows thing.